# How to add CTA buttons in emails

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS server with Rest APIs and I want to create an email with basic accept/reject buttons. I already have the APIs implemented but for react-native app use not in email.

My question is, how do I call the APIs using the buttons I will create in my email, As far as I know I can only add a link to a button when clicked so I have to put all the data in query parameters right ? Also, I have `JWT` authentication for the APIs. So how can I do that exactly in a link ?

Thanks!

Comment: As you said yourself: The only possibility in an email is a link with query parameters, so you have to put all necessary data in those parameters. And if it's your own api, you can decide to accept the JWT also from query parameters ...

Comment: is it secure to pass the JWT in query params

Comment: Depends on the token. If you can restrict your token to allow this specific call only it might be ok. I personally would not send a JWT via email but create some sort of onetime-token that allows that specific request only and is disabled once it is used.